# Python no module named numpy

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

I want to run a python example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,3,4,5,7,9,13,15,17]
plt.plot(x)
plt.ylabel('Sunlight')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

When I' try to run: **python plot.py** in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS terminal, I get this output: ImportError: No Module named 'numpy'. I have installed numpy by running this command: **sudo apt-get install python3-numpy**. I'm using Python 3.5. How can I make Ubuntu/Python in order to import numpy module?

Answer (score 2):

You must exec `python3 plot.py`.

Or if you want to run `python` (that is, python2), you must install `python-numpy`.

Note that you can also exec you script direct:

```
$ chmod +x plot.py
$ ./ploy.py
```

to use `python3` change the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Already tried to run: python3 plot.py also python3.5 plot.py and same problem.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that `python3-numpy` is installed? (check with `dpkg -s python3-numpy`). Have you noted that you example doesn't need numpy? Have you tried with python2?

Comment: Yes, **numpy** is installed. Package: python3-numpy, Status: install ok installed. I'm try to run example from this [link] (http://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/line-charts/)

Comment: No positive results with python2. I have both python2.7 and python3.5 installed. Could be some compatibility issues!?

Comment: Solved. Used to run: sudo pip3 install numpy. But now is another problem :), can't install matlibplot. I get some error but I will find a way to solve it. Thanks @malbarbo for your support!!!